# Android studio not responding when i run my app

Tags: android

I write a app about location service,and there have been a emulator launched since i began checking my code. And what the problem is that the software does not responding after i click the "run app" button ,only mouse can move,and my internal storage has much left,is there some advice upon this problem,any suggestion will be appreciated! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is very memory heavy so it might be a good idea not to run other proccesses while you are running the app/emulator or kill unwanted proccesses in the task manager. Updating Android Studio may also help.

Comment: My software edition is the most recent one,and the internal storage is 10 G,also i didn't run other proccesses, i have tried to close the software and emulator ,it just don't response ,so i just shut them down through the task manager,thanks for your advice@James Swift